# Decoy User Account on Windows

Tags: passwords

Is there a way to have two passwords for a Windows account? One password unlocks the decoy version of the account and the other unlocks the "real" version of the account. I would use Truecrypt's hidden OS feature but don't want to reboot the computer.

Answer (score 4):

Not natively, no. You would have to have some 3rd party authentication mechanism that loads up a second account when a different password is entered.

Comment: Not to mention, you need to stop one account being able to just read the other account files on the hard drive.

Comment: Well, that can be done natively through proper ACL'ing.

Answer (score 1):

How ever, you can select a similar looking account ID. For example - instead of ADMINISTRATOR, you may use ADM1N1STRATOR, etc. Good when you just want to use it as a decoy, however, the admin account can be found out via the SID.

Comment: What good would this do exactly?  This seems useless to 99% of the attacks that exist to harvest a user's password.

Comment: Can help sometimes when you are trying to avoid shoulder surfing.

Answer (score 0):

No, the closest thing I can think of is dual booting two versions of windows and having it default to the decoy. You'd need to use separate full drive encryption volumes so they can't access each other's files. As long as they use the same account names, desktop bg and screensaver it'll make a reasonable decoy, the only real problem is that you can't switch accounts from a lock screen.

Comment: What you're referring to sounds a whole lot like a [TrueCrypt Hidden Operating System](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=hidden-operating-system).

Comment: Didn't know Truecrypt supported that but that's pretty much the same thing.